# Simple performance test

Tags: performance, web-applications

I am creating a webapp that requires broad coverage on a variety of devices.  I have implemented version tests to determine if feature coverage applies.  This allows me to determine if a user is able to support the full set of features available and either disable those features or give the user an appropriate 'not supported' message.  What I have found is that even version number does not infer sufficient performance; that is, at least some bare minimum processing and memory requirements remain (specifically, some older Android 'budget' devices may have a recent Android version but lack the performance necessary to run a feature-rich multimedia web app).  If I were to implement a quick and seemless performance test, such that I downgrade features based on performance rather than version, how might such a feature be implemented?

If I were creating a Canvas-based game, I might check the framerate and progressively downgrade the experience.  But for a DOM-based web app, what is the best way to check the "framerate"--a fast and reliable performance metric test that I can run right when the user visits the page.

Comment: Have you considered using a "blacklist" of devices that you know will not work (or a "whitelist" for those that works ok). That way you could keep a list of devices that are supported/unsupported to check against (and then fallback to the simplest version if necessary). For Chrome on Android f.i. you could check the Build tag in the user agent string to get some idea of what phone it is... https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/user-agent

Comment: Is there a way to determine a specific device?  I can't rely on the OS or browser version, since the problem is really due to the device's processing speed and memory capacity (and, perhaps, due to some other multitasked apps hogging resources).  I'd like to do something akin to a streaming service downgrading the video quality on slow connections, so I might turn off alpha channel rendering, etc. to improve performance.  Basically, what's the best way to determine performance thresholds as opposed to browser/device version.

Comment: I looked in to it a bit more and while some device manufacturer includes the device name in the Android **Build Tag etc.** part of the UA (like "HTC Desire", "Galaxy Nexus") it won't identify ALL devices sadly. I think you're on the right track using feature detection along with a simple performance test. If your app is doing alot of DOM manipulation then you could incorporate the test in a loading "animation" adding new elements and checking how fast that is completed. Perhaps you could just have your user make a choice though e.g. Limited, Medium and Full featured?

Comment: We're definitely on the same page, was thinking about a performance test at the loading animation earlier.  In fact I'm thinking that the animation itself would be the stress test.  I think your idea about adding DOM elements is good, but is it the best?  Some features might lean on hardware graphics acceleration while others rely on the CPU, so what are some good ways of testing this?  The solution I'd like to put down in this thread would be a routine or two that do a nice job of establishing a performance benchmark that can be performed with minimal visibility to the end-user.